# AJAX - Change content based on reply from PHP Script

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

**Scenario**
I have a page where users can activate or deactivate the service. I have got a button where it says the current state of the service. I achieve this by getting service state via php and echoing  `active` or `inactive` at the place of the button text.

**Problem** I want a AJAX to listen for click on the button. When a user clicks on the `active` button the AJAX should call a url which triggers change of the users' service state change and returns the current state of the user. I want to change the text in the button to `active` if the reply was `200` and `inactive` if the reply from the php was `101`.

I want to compare the result in a if-elseif-else style statement like

```
    if(reply=='200')
       code-to-change-the-text-to-active;
    elseif(reply=='101')
       code-to-change-the-text-to-in;
    else
       alert(some-error);
```

---

I made several searches and only found how to change the text with the text from the reply. But, I want a way to fetch the reply as variable and use it to switch my text.

Comment: Just return JSON from your PHP page that you call via AJAX.  To do this, read here http://www.islandsmooth.com/2010/04/send-and-receive-json-data-using-ajax-jquery-and-php/

Answer (score 1):

You need to send your reply from PHP to JavaScript as JSON (using json_encode($reply)), then, your AJAX success callback function will receive the state value in a format it can use.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code format with your actual data:

HTML

```
<input type="button" value="active" id="active">
```

JS

```
$('#active').click(function () {  
       var status = $(this).attr('value'); // get the value of your button state
       var r = confirm("Are You Sure Change Status?");
       if (r==true){
          $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "YOUR URL",
             data:"{userstatus:status}",
             beforeSend : function () {

             },
             success:function(result){
                 //Do whatever you want with result//
             }
          });
       }else{
          return false;
       }
    });
```

**Note:** when you click on the active button its call ajax function and put your actual  url file name in url param. then run the sql query there and you will get response in success as result.

Comment: Sorry if I am asking to spoonfeed but I have got no clue of AJAX/JS. Can you supply the html for this so that I can relate to the elements and learn the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

shortcut/ fast.

**JS**

function updateStatus(){

```
$.get('yourPHPCode/getStatus', function(data) ){
    $('#status').val(data);
}
```

}

**PHP**

function getStatus(){
  ...
  echo $status;
}